# Legend formatting for ggplot with geom_col and geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am attempting to do the following code to get a legend that has a red line for "Capacity" and a black box for "Demand" instead of the legend in the image with a black box with red outline for "Capacity"

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y2)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x,y2,colour = "Capacity")) + 
  geom_col(aes(x,y1,colour="Demand"), fill = "black") + 
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  labs(title = paste("Optimal Schedule", check[[4]], "-", check[[5]], sep = " "), x = "Time (hours)", y = "Driver Hours") + 
  ylim(0,max(df$y3)) + 
  scale_colour_manual("", values = c("red", "black"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c("solid","blank")), shape = c(NA,NA)))
```

Graph with incorrect legend
[image: graph with incorrect legend]

Comment: Why not `geom_line(aes(x,y2,colour = "Capacity")) ` and  `geom_col(aes(x,y1, fill="Demand"))`

Comment: You could use a `scale_fill_manual(values = c(Capactity = NA, Demand = "black")`

Comment: I think you should be using `geom_area` not `geom_col` here.

Comment: Amusingly, I ended up here making a plot of the same exact variables!

Answer (score 1):

Map `fill` for `geom_col` (or `geom_area`, looks the same):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Capacity = cumsum(rnorm(1000)))
df$Time <- 1:nrow(df)
df$Demand <- df$Capacity * 0.8

ggplot(df, aes(x = Time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Capacity,colour = "Capacity")) + 
  geom_col(aes(y = Demand, fill = "Demand"))  +
  scale_colour_manual("", values = c("red")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black"))
```

[image]